# Переход на якорь(#) через <div onClick()>

Tags: html, html5

Я пытаюсь перейти на блок, по клику мыши на другом блоке.

Сейчас у меня реализовано это примерно так:

```
<div class="result_container">
    <a href="#dialog" name="modal">
        ...
    </a>
</div>


<div id="dialog" class="window">
```

Но! Кликнуть можно лишь на элементы, которые содержаться внутри блока, а на пустую область внутри div'а - нельзя. Помогите пожалуйста - как решить эту проблему? Пытался сделать через onClick div'а, но не срабатывает.

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='#dialog'">
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya  как я знаю это работает только для ссылок. Чтобы работало для div делайте в js

Comment: `<a href="#dialog" name="modal">`<div class="result_container">...</div>`</a>` — А что мешает сделать наоборот?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо большое, прямо зациклился на этом и не подумал

Comment: Такой код не пройдёт валидацию ибо `нельзя размещать внутри тега <a> блочные элементы`. Плохо что разработчики браузеров не сочли нужным дабы "кодеры" соблюдали стандарты

Comment: А если нельзя, но везде работает - не равно "можно" ? (кстати, где официально записываются эти особенности?)

Answer (score 1):

Всё прекрасно работает...

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.result_container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
}

#dialog {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="result_container" onclick="window.location.href='#dialog'">
</div>
<div id="dialog" class="window">
</div>
```